# How to change the obstacle rules in enchant.js?

Tags: javascript, enchantjs

I'm making a RPG game with enchant.js,and then I created a map like this:
[sample map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqjuT.png)

The players can not pass through the water,but when players take a boat,they can pass through.My question is that should I have to rewrite the collistionData each time when players walking/boating?Is there a easy way to do that if the map is large?Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with enchant.js, but typically how this is handled is using collision masks. So depending on what physics engine you're using, there should be a way to set collision mask values (use integers) on the physics bodies. With box2d for example you have two values:

1. category bits
2. mask bits

The category is the number value that this object is or the type. So if you have a bunch of variables:

```
const PLAYER = 1;
const WATER = 2;
const BOAT = 4;
```

You would set the category bits to one of them. The mask bits is then the value of what masks it can collide with.

```
const PlayerEntity = {
  category: PLAYER,
  mask: PLAYER | WATER
};

const WaterEntity = {
  category: WATER,
  mask: PLAYER
};
```

What physics engines do internally with this is an & operation to see if the category and mask values equate to something else than 0. If it does, then there's a collision.

Comment: it seems that enchant.js use a different way to implement obstacle on map.It has an array like [0,0,0,1,1] which was assigned by developer at game first loading(1 represents can not pass through),it's hard to rewrite in game.But your answer is awesome and helpful to me,thanks~~

Comment: Ah okay. I had a look at the docs, but didnt see much on collisions :)

Comment: [http://enchantjs.com/tutorial/lets-start-with-enchant-js/#ref_10](http://enchantjs.com/tutorial/lets-start-with-enchant-js/#ref_10) gives an example to add collision on map,but it will hard to deassign when game is running.

Comment: Ah okay. My answer is the way to go if you move up to something like Phaser+p2 or melonjs, but for what you posted, I would update the values via the array index of `map.collisionData` as you need to. Maybe just make a note of what tiles are the water ones in another collection or something.

Comment: I can't agree more.It will be a large job if the map have 1000 X 1000 tiles.